# -bash: [: =: unary operator expected. when no parameter given

Tags: bash, shell

I have my shell script, `myscript.sh` below

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ $1 = "-r" ]; then
    echo "I am here"
fi
```

If I run with `. myscript.sh -r`, it works well with message `I am here`.

But if I just run with `. myscript.sh`, it complaints

`-bash: [: =: unary operator expected`

What's missing in my script?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You would need to add quotes around $1.

```
if [ "$1" = "-r" ]; then
    echo "I am here"
fi
```

When $1 is empty you are getting if [ = "-r"] which is a syntax error.

Answer (score 11):

You have missed the quotes:

```
if [ "$1" = "-r" ]; then
```