# Get the path of the script executed in Source Bash script

Tags: bash, shell

When I run `sh ./mypath/myscript.sh` with the code below,

```
BASEDIR=$(dirname "$0")
echo "$BASEDIR"
```

I got `./mypath` which is great.

However, since I need to `source` due to [-bash: [: =: unary operator expected. when no parameter given](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42637238/3286489),

The above code doesn't work, but just return `-bash` instead. Is there an equivalent of the above code that work when `source` instead of `sh`?

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #28](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/028).

Comment: and btw, `sh` isn't bash; if you run `sh yourscript`, then the only capabilities guaranteed to be present are those specified in the POSIX sh standard. Even if your system's POSIX sh interpreter *is* bash, it runs in a barebones compatibility mode with lots of features turned off when invoked that way. Always use `bash yourscript`, or a `#!/bin/bash` shebang, to ensure that full functionality is available.

Comment: Cool. The answer to my inquiry is `DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"`

Comment: In most circumstances, `dir=${BASH_SOURCE%/*}` will suffice without the other fanciness. (Aside: All-caps variable names are reserved for use by variables with meaning to the operating system or shell; using lowercase names for your own variables avoids overwriting meaningful ones by accident. See relevant POSIX spec at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, paragraph 4, keeping in mind that setting a shell variable with a name matching any preexisting environment variable will overwrite the latter).